# CiviEvent : display future and past events

Tags: civievent, joomla

I have two issues on a Joomla website, I want to display future and past events from the CiviEvent component on the front-end but it doesn't work.

Future events: the website only displays the next event and I can't find an option to have more than 1 on the page. Where would I change this ?

Past events : I didn't find anything to display past events on the front-end, there's no menu item available to do this. How can I display them ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The CiviCRM HTML listing URL may help.

By default this displays all current and upcoming events that are active and have been set to public –

/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&html=1

You can add parameters to this URL to filter by dates and event types –

This example will display events that start from 1st Jan 2019 -

/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&html=1&start=20190101

This example will display events of type conference (type=1 is the ID of event type Conference)-

/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&html=1type=1

This example will display events of type conference AND with a start date >= 1st Jan 2019 –

/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&html=1&start=20190101&type=1

You can use the end date parameter to display past events, for example, this link will display all events that were held in 2018 -

/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&html=1&start=20180101&end=20181231

Downsides without any development –

The title of all the pages will display as Current and Upcoming events even if you are displaying past events.

You can’t remove/add/reorder the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify your question?

When you mean display past / Future events in the front end do you mean just showing a link?

It would be helpful if you provide a screenshot.