# How can I generate iCal feed URLs that users can subscribe to in their preferred calendar applications?

Tags: civievent

I want to provide users with a range of iCal feed URLs for different event types. Looking at this post: [CiviEvent : display future and past events](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22998/civievent-display-future-and-past-events/27818#27818) it seems that I can specify a type=X parameter in the query string.

For most of these events I ideally want to not have the events set to be public as they are invitation-only, and also because I want to include links to Zoom calls in the iCal entries - and it looks like in order to do that the data needs to be in a field that is included in the iCal data so I can't easily use a custom field to store that information. And of course I don't want to publish Zoom links on the site such that anyone can easily find and use them. Can I include non-public events in an iCal feed?

Comment: possible off topic but you know there is some zoom integration?

Comment: Thanks Pete. If you are referring to https://civicrm.org/extensions/civizoom then that's not really useful in our case. We aren't concerned about having people registered within Zoom. My main interest is how to simply get relevant event data into people's calendars. Having them register for every event is a PITA for them when there might be 5 or 6 meetings each month. iCal feeds feel like a possible solution.

Comment: I've found this extension from Civicoop which looks to work with current releases of CiviCRM, and might just do the job. https://civicrm.org/extensions/orgcivicoopeventprivateical If that proves to be the case I'll provide an answer.

Comment: "Having them register for every event is a PITA ".. we have an extension so you set one event as the 'parent' event. set others as 'child' events by referencing the parent event ID. then someone registering for the parent one gets registered for all the children too. may not be useful but you never know.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe. Got a link for that extension?

Comment: has never been published. if you email me i can flick you a zip to try out on a dev environment

Comment: it will need a tweak i expect to match the custom field that needs setting up for it.